# Create a snapshot of a vm through azure powershell (arm)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, snapshot, azure-managed-disk

The VM with unmanaged disks.
The following cmndlet can be used to take snapshot of a managed disk (ARM)
    $snapshot =  New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig 
      `-SourceUri $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id`
      -Location $location `
      -CreateOption copy
How can this be done for a vm with unmanaged disk ?

Comment: for unmanaged disk just copy the underlying vhd?

Comment: SourceUri $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.vhd do you mean this @4c74356b41 ?I did that but I got an error saying invalid source id.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brainscale.com/blogs/azure-arm-vm-snapshot/ like so you could snapshot the underlying storage, you can also use UI to create managed disk or you can create a managed disk from the vhd.

```
#Provide the subscription Id where Managed Disks will be created
$subscriptionId = 'yourSubscriptionId'

#Provide the name of your resource group where Managed Disks will be created. 
$resourceGroupName ='yourResourceGroupName'

#Provide the name of the Managed Disk
$diskName = 'yourDiskName'

#Provide the size of the disks in GB. It should be greater than the VHD file size.
$diskSize = '128'

#Provide the storage type for Managed Disk. PremiumLRS or StandardLRS.
$storageType = 'PremiumLRS'

#Provide the Azure region (e.g. westus) where Managed Disk will be located.
#This location should be same as the storage account where VHD file is stored
#Get all the Azure location using command below:
#Get-AzureRmLocation
$location = 'westus'

#Provide the URI of the VHD file (page blob) in a storage account. Please not that this is NOT the SAS URI of the storage container where VHD file is stored. 
#e.g. https://contosostorageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/contosovhd123.vhd
#Note: VHD file can be deleted as soon as Managed Disk is created.
$sourceVHDURI = 'https://contosostorageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/contosovhd123.vhd'

#Provide the resource Id of the storage account where VHD file is stored.
#e.g. /subscriptions/6472s1g8-h217-446b-b509-314e17e1efb0/resourceGroups/MDDemo/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/contosostorageaccount
#This is an optional parameter if you are creating managed disk in the same subscription
$storageAccountId = '/subscriptions/yourSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/yourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/yourStorageAccountName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where Managed Disk will be created
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Import -StorageAccountId $storageAccountId -SourceUri $sourceVHDURI

New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName
```

and snapshot it after.  [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-managed-disk-from-vhd). Not sure, but snapshots might not be available for unmanaged disks (dont quote me on this).